# Hello World Module in PyroCMS

Tags: module, pyrocms

How to develop a Hello World Module in PyroCMS

Answer (score 3):

You can download the hello world module for PyroCMS from following link

http://blog.developeronhire.com/pyrocms-hello-world-module/

Hope you like it

Comment: developeronhire.com seems down when I've checked...

Answer (score 1):

here is [Hello world PyroCMS module](http://bhu1st.blogspot.com/2010/09/hello-world-pyrocms-module.html), check once. that's my blog.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official [sample module](https://github.com/pyrocms/sample) too.